# Adding subviews to NSView

Tags: macos, xcode4, nsview

I want to add subview to NSView dynamically. I set the coordinates of NSView as :

```
NSView *tmpView = [[NSView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

I want to add dynamic number of imageViews to tmpView. My imageView is as:

```
NSImageView *tmpImageView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 320, 180)];
```

Here, xAxis and yAxis are for positioning of imageViews dynamically.

When i add image view to NSView as:

```
[tmpView addSubView:tmpImageView]
```

It adds imageView from bottom left corner but i want it to start from top left corner. Please help how can i add subViews accordingly to NSView.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass your view and override `-isFlipped` to return `YES`. See [the NSView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) where it says:

> -(BOOL)isFlipped
>   Returns YES if the receiver uses flipped drawing coordinates or NO if it uses native 
>   coordinates.

Comment: Actually i was having problems in overriding the NSVIew function now it is done. Thanks